# Forcing the MobX state to be changed through declared actions only in the Flutter framework

Tags: flutter, dart, mobx, state-management

I'm experimenting with MobX state management solution in Flutter. I really like its conciseness and its simplicity but I'm a bit concerned in the drawbacks its way of mutating the state can introduce.
Theoretically , we can force the state to be mutated only using actions and this is great because we can have a history of the changes using the spy feature the package provides.
However, actions are automatically created by the framework if we do not use a specific one. For example, in the code below, I created a counter store class and I used it in the main function to assign a new value for the counter without using a predeclared action. The stric-mode has been previously set to "always".

```
abstract class _Counter with Store {
  @observable
  int value = 0;

  @action
  void increment() {
    value++;
  }
}

final counter = Counter(); // Instantiate the store
void main() {
  mainContext.config = mainContext.config
      .clone(isSpyEnabled: true, writePolicy: ReactiveWritePolicy.always);
  mainContext.spy((event) {
    print("event name : " + event.name);
    print("event type : " + event.type);
  });
  Counter counter = Counter();
  counter.value = 10;
}
```

I was expecting an error to raise saying that it is not possible to change the state outside of action but this does not happen because an ad hoc action is created , called value_set, automatically. I'm wondering ,then, which is the point of forcing to use actions if it is possible to avoid using   them. I mean, if we directly change the state, an action is created automatically and seen by the spy functionality making all the process more robust and predictable but, what if I want the state to be changed only by actions I previously implemented? Is there a way of doing so? For example, in the counter code I just provided , is there a way of making the counter incrementalbe only by 1? Because, in the way Mobx works, I could write everywhere in the code something like

```
counter.value = 10
```

and this will work just fine without any problems. Forcing people to use preset actions could increase the predicatability a lot and facilitate the teamwork too I think.
I tried to make the value variable private but it still remains accessible from the outside , also if annotated with @readonly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I found out that the behaviour I was looking for was obtainable with the `@readonly` annotation. Marking a variable with `@readonly` annotation avoids automatically creating its setter and getter methods. Moreover it requires the annotated variable to be `private`, denying the variable to be set directly.

***Note:*** By the way, the way the Dart language is implemented, it is necessary to locate the `Counter` in a separate file to provide the desired behaviour, otherwise its private fields would be accessible anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, that looks weird for me too, because it does work differently in MobX JS (exactly like you describing), but it seems that Dart MobX changed behaviour for single field values and they are automatically wrapped in actions now, yes.

Maybe there should be a optional rule to turn strict checking on again, it would make sense. I suggest you to create and issue or discussion on Dart MobX Github.

More info there: https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx.dart/issues/206

Comment: Thanks, I opened up an issue on the mobx.dart git 
https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx.dart/issues/729
Doing some further research, I found out that the @readonly annotation should be the correct way to fullfil my goal, however it seems to don't work as intended.